# Parameter bindings in ssis

Tags: ssis, parameter-passing, parent-child

How to dynamically pass value to the child package variable by using Execute Package Task?

I need to call a package(child) from another package (parent) concurrently. In every call, I require to pass different value to child package variable

I have tried using parameter bindings in Execute Package Task but, some where I made mistake. Its not passing value as expected. Passing only empty
[image]

Eg:

one parent and one child. 3 different tasks to run same child. I want to pass 3 different variables from parent to a single child variable

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you checked if the variable in de parent package contains the expected value?

Comment: I dont know if I am doing any good here. can you not update the parameter values from the parent package in a flat file and let the child package pickup those values from that same file as he latter begins?

Comment: I agree @BhupeshC. Even easier if you update via a control record in a database table

Comment: @JodyT : Yes variable having the expected value

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To pass a variable from a parent package to a child package, you can use **Package Configurations**.

In your **parent package**, create the variable you want to pass the value from. Let's call it **varParent**. Now, use an Execute Package Task to reference the child package. You don't need any parameter bindings.

In your **child package**, create the variable that will receive the value from the parent package - **varChild**. Right click on an empty space in the Control Flow and select Properties. Scroll to **Configurations** under Misc. and click the button with the three dots.

Check "Enable package configurations" and click Add. The Package Configuration Wizard opens. Click Next.
In Configuration type, select **Parent package variable**. In the Parent variable field, enter **varParent**. Click Next.

In the tree view folder structure that shows, expand Variables, **varChild**, Properties and select **Value**. Click Next.

[image]

Give your Configuration a name and click Finish. Close the Package Configurations Organizer.

Now, you **varChild** will get the value from **varParent**.

Comment: What if I don't want to create a variable for each value I'd want to pass in the future?
For example, If I'm executing the same package 100 times, each time a different value needs to be specified for the parameter. I don't want to create 100 variables.
I could create one variable, then add an expression task after each package execution to update its value but I'd like to avoid that if possible.